# fseek, fread and return the pointer (C) in binary file function not working properly

Tags: c, pointers, fread, fseek

I want to return the pointer to the structure that I read from the file (it goes to another functions that basicaly just prints the data.) 
Function gets the (serial number -1) through int sem, and then the idea was, to set the file pointer to the beginning of the structure that I want to read with the fseek, and simply read the whole structure and return the pointer. 
(Example: If the number of the structures written in the file is 5 and I want to read the structure no. 4, the sem value that function gets is 3, then with fseek pointer skips the first 3 structures and function reads and return the strucutre no.4).
It works fine if the sem value is 0, but not so fine when I seek for any other structure. I have no idea what goes wrong! Help? :)

```
type_seminar *file_seminars_search(int sem) {
     type_seminar *temp_s = (type_seminar*) malloc(sizeof(type_seminar));
     FILE *f_sem;
     if ((f_sem = fopen("seminars.bin", "r")) != NULL ) {
          fseek(f_sem, sem * sizeof(type_seminar), SEEK_SET);
          fread(temp_s, sizeof(type_seminar), 1, f_sem);
          fclose(f_sem);
          return (temp_s);
     } else
          printf("Cannot access file. \n ");
     return 0;
}
```

The definition of strucutre:

```
typedef struct {
     char s_title[A];
     char s_street[B];
     char s_town[C];
     int max_no_teachers;
     int no_applied_teachers;
} type_seminar;
```

- [Contents of the seminars.txt file](http://www.flickr.com/photos/92976167@N05/8454761716/in/photostream/)
- [What it prints on the screen if I choose the second structure in the file](http://www.flickr.com/photos/92976167@N05/8454761702/in/photostream)

And the function that prints data if the problem is in here:

```
void seminar_details(type_seminar *temp_s) {
      printf("   SEMINAR TITLE : %s", temp_s->s_title);
      printf("   Street: %s ", temp_s->s_street);
      printf("   Town: %s", temp_s->s_town);
      printf("   Max no of applied teachers: %d \n", temp_s->max_no_teachers);
      printf("   No of applied teachers: %d \n", temp_s->no_applied_teachers);
}
```

Comment: How did you create the file ? Are you absolutely convinced there's a structure there ?

Comment: Define "not so fine". If you have an error, look at the symptoms, make a theory about the symptom cause, test the theory and fix the error. Especially, I suspect that the size of the type_seminar struct and the record stride in the file are unequal. Could you show an extract of the file, please?

Comment: File was created with fopen("w"), and there is a structure 100%, because it worked when I was going through file with for loop (actually reading every single structure and stoppin when it reached the one that I wanted to return)...

Comment: I don't understand how it fails. Does `* temp_s` contain garbage? Take a peek at your file with `hexdump`, try to see the structs in it. Do the `for` again, but use `ftell` to get the start of each record, and compare.

Comment: Triple check that you didn't mess up something elsewhere...

Comment: @vonbrand I did as you suggested, and the ftell value is different than sem * sizeof(type_seminar) value (already) after the first fread... I will leave the for loop solution, but I still wonder what goes wrong... Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your data file `seminars.bin` seems to contains new line (`\n`). You should create it with `"wb"` not `"w"` and open it with `"rb"`. If you  access with text mode, your library provided by Microsoft will convert `\n` to `\r\n` and data length will be changed.

Comment: That's what I just did :) It's working :) Thanks! (Thanks for the explanation as well! )

Answer (score 1):

I feel that the way seminars.bin was created will determine the way the file is read. It may also be helpful to open your file in binary mode as compared to ascii mode.

I used the following function to create the seminars.bin

```
void createData()
{
FILE    *fcre;
type_seminar element;
int counter;

fcre = fopen("seminars.bin", "wb");
for(counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
{
    printf("Enter type_seminar.s_title:");
    scanf("%s", element.s_title);
    printf("Enter type_seminar.s_street:");
    scanf("%s", element.s_street);
    printf("Enter type_seminar.s_town:");
    scanf("%s", element.s_town);
    printf("Enter type_seminar.max_no_teachers:");
    scanf("%d", &element.max_no_teachers);
    printf("Enter type_seminar.no_applied_teachers:");
    scanf("%d", &element.no_applied_teachers);

    fwrite(&element, sizeof(type_seminar), 1, fcre);
}
fclose(fcre);
}
```

I modified a couple of lines in your original file as

```
if ((f_sem = fopen("seminars.bin", "rb")) != NULL )
```

and

```
 fread(temp_s, sizeof(type_seminar), 1, f_sem);
```

With these changes, I could get your code to work as per your expected design!!

Comment: No the arrays were not completely filled( A=100, B=50, C=20 ) and by the "size is an integral multiple of 4" you mean that I should set A to at least 200 if the size of the string that goes in _title is 50? (sorry for my english)

Comment: It's working! I cant believe it! The only thing that I actually had to  change in whole code is add the 'b' in "rb". Thanks! :D

Answer (score -1):

Problem is at

```
return 0;
```

line. 
because you're not returning int.

Comment: It is meant as `return NULL`. I don't think this is the problem.